# Objectify 5 - filter embedded entity field doesn't work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I try to load a list of objects from my own class called 'Payment'. Now I do not want to load all payments but only those who have a specific 'Group' as parent (Group is also an own class).

This is the Payment class:

```
@Entity
public class Payment {
    @Id private Long id;
    @Index @Load private Ref<Group> parent;
    // other fields, constructors, getters and setters
}
```

And this is my Group class:

```
@Entity
public class Group {
    @Index @Id private Long id;
    // other fields, constructors, getters and setters
}
```

The following is the method in which I try to load this list of payments:

```
public static List<Payment> getPaymentsByGroup(Group group) {
    List<Payment> payments = ofy().load().type(Payment.class)
            .filter("parent.id", group.getId()).list();
    return payments;
}
```

But the result is always an empty list. But if I try to do something like this:

```
public static List<Payment> getPaymentsByGroup(Group group) {
    List<Payment> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Payment> payments = ofy().load().type(Payment.class).list();
    for (Payment payment : payments) {
        if(payment.getParent().getId().equals(group.getId())){
            temp.add(payment);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I'll get my payments. I use Objectify 5. Because of the performance, the Payment class should be an own Entity and not be stored as a normal embedded object in the Group class. Otherwise the whole group object would have to be stored with all payments by adding one single payment.

What am I doing wrong? How can I filter a field in an embedded entity?

Comment: I think you might be confusing terminology here as I don't see a `@Parent` (entity group) or an embedded entity.  I do see a `Ref<?>`, which is essentially a key.  What happens if you change your query to `List<Payment> payments = ofy().load().type(Payment.class)
            .filter("parent = ", Ref.create(group)).list();` ?

Comment: oh well thank you that solved my problem. i tried something similar to that but it did not work. Tkans!

Comment: Great to hear. I've added my comment as an answer in case you want to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be confusing terminology here as I don't see a `@Parent` (entity group) or an embedded entity. I do see a `Ref<?>`, which is essentially a Key.

If you change your query to

`List<Payment> payments = ofy().load().type(Payment.class).filter("parent = ", Ref.create(group)).list();`

it should work.